# Recompiling a part of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Wanting to take advantage (for the first time) of the open-source nature of open-source software, I want to edit part of Google Chrome. I know exactly which source file to edit, and it's a very small change. However, the entire *compressed* source distribution tarball is about a gigabyte, and I can't even imagine how painful the recompiling process would be, not to mention how much disk space it would use.

So, the question is: Is there any better way to modify the program than to recompile the entire thing? It seems to be quite a painful thing to do for small changes.

Comment: Once you've built it once, it's probably much quicker to rebuild if you're only making smallish changes. And 10GB really isn't that much space these days. Download the tarball, update, then just let it build overnight. Come back the next day, make your changes, incremental build, and it should be manageable.

Comment: I know with Firefox a good portion of it is plain text files located in .jar files that can be extracted (they are zip files), edited, and recompressed. I would do that to move menu items around, rename stuff, etc. back when I cared about stuff like that

Comment: @Anon: The issue isn't just the size, it's also the *number* of files -- it would make my NTFS file tables blow up by around 100%. (Maybe it's just me, but I absolutely hate extracting more than a thousand files from an archive for small reasons.) Is there really no better way?  @scragz: That seems interesting... I'm not sure if it works with Chrome, but I'll take a look; thanks.

Comment: Yeah, a significant part of Firefox code is in Javascript, CSS, and XUL(XML-based GUI for Gecko). If what you want to achieve can be done by simply editing the code packed in `.jar`, it would be much easier. You can even write a shell script for downloading and modifying official Mozilla binary tarball.

Comment: @Anon: Side question: Let's say that I actually compile it. Is there any way to synchronize the changes with the online server without checking out the entire source each time, so that my version doesn't become outdated? (I'm guessing this requires more knowledge of SVN than what I have, so if that's the case, then just let me know and I'll go read up on it.) Thanks! :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Just regularly pull updates. The point of version control is that once you have the source, you only need to download the changes, rather than redownloading the whole thing each time something is modified.

Comment: @Anon: Okay, thanks. Yeah, I'm a little familiar with the concept of version control, but not enough to know how simple the comands would be. I downloaded the tarball; let's see how it goes. :]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no other way recompiling Chromium. I recommend you to use the Google Chrome Extensions API if you can. If you want to recompile Google Chrome, the steps are pretty easy, everything is explained in http://dev.chromium.org/developers Some tips (since I am a Chromium contributor)

1. For a quick start guide: https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dd9mrt45_0dmtd49c6
2. Read documentation: http://dev.chromium.org/developers
3. Make sure you have 10GB of space.
4. Make sure you have a fast computer (64bit), the more cores/mem the better.
5. The source code is "not" just 1GB, it is more, after you checkout the sources, you would need to sync your DEPS (thirdparty) via `gclient sync` That will add another couple of GB.

It will take a lot of time to compile (~1 hour) on modern PCs. If you have a very fast computer, the time of compilation would decrease exponentially.

According to you comments above, you would need to checkout the source at least once, we use Git or SVN for that ([read the documentations](http://dev.chromium.org/developers), we have explained as much as we can on the site). Once you finished compilation, you can always update your source (the same way you update your repository (git pull, gclient sync) Then incremental buildings will be around 5-10 minutes depending what you have changed.

Please follow the documentation (http://dev.chromium.org), I am saying that again because the Chromium community worked hard to make these documentations up-to date, they help new comers get familiar with the project.

Chromium is big, but fun to work with, have fun hacking :)

Comment: Will it still take ~1 hour to compile on modern PCs?

Answer (score 2):

The open sourced [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/) is ***not*** the same thing as Google Chrome. Some specific features (like H264 support) are available in Chrome, but not Chromium. You cannot "build" Chrome; you can build Chromium.

A more feasible approach to make your modification might be to write it as an [Extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html).

Comment: I did *not* know that! I *was* wondering why they had different names and why the version numbers seemed inconsistent, but didn't really give it a second thought. +1 Thanks a lot for the clarification!